# Can the user set the time the push alarm sounds on the pwa? Also, can you make the alarm persist?

Tags: react-native, web-applications, push-notification, frontend, progressive-web-apps

Hello I am trying to build a webapp using pwa.
I am trying to set an alarm by giving an app push at a time set by the user.
I have a few questions, and I would be very grateful if you could tell me how to implement it as well. (Even if it is not a method, I would be very grateful if you could tell me if it is possible!)

1. Can I make a push alarm go off at a user-specified time with pwa?
2. Can you make it vibrate and sound after the push alarm goes off until the user wakes up and presses Badge?
3. Can I make the push alarm go off every 5 minutes (a specific time)?

I am a beginner doing a toy project. I'm not good at development, so I'm asking a question.
I really appreciate it if you can help me :)
have a good day!

PS If the above functions are not possible with pwa, I am trying to implement it using react native, but is swift or kotlin used a lot?